# PHP Generate Array by 2 Values

Tags: php

I have 2 values:
Value 1 = 423749
Value 2 = 328493

Value 1 = 20%
Value 2 = 80% (What is left from Value 1 - 100%)

```
 $Array_Generator = array(
  'Max_Values'   => 200,
  'Values'       => array(
   'Value_1'      => array(
    'Value'        => 423749,
    'Percent'      => 20, // %
   ),
   'Value_2'      => array(
    'Value'        => 328493,
    'Percent'      => 80, // %
   ),
  ),
 );
```

By Max Array Values = 200

I need a PHP to be able to generate an array with 200 values and Value 1 = 20% of the array and to be included random position on the array example

Value 1
Value 2
Value 2
Value 1
Value 2
Value 2
Value 2
Value 1

How to create a PHP array generator to be able to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain your example a bit more? It's not clear what you want to generate or how these percentages are connected to your numbers. Also, please include your effort at solving this.

Comment: Hello, i update the question with an example array but including a solving way I don't know how to start on this, if I was knowing I will not be here

Comment: You're expected to show us some indication that you've tried to solve your problem. Maybe some code, even if it's broken. As it stands, this question is too broad and is also likely to [attract downvotes](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do here or how these numbers are connected.

Comment: You could create the array first and then use suffle to mix the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your specific question...
The script below will generate an array with 200 keys such that it contains 20% of value 1s and 80% of values 2s randomly

```php
$val_1p = $Array_Generator['Values']['Value_1']['Percent']; //Get percentage of value 1
$value_1 = $Array_Generator['Values']['Value_1']['Value']; //Get actual value of value 1

$val_2p = $Array_Generator['Values']['Value_2']['Percent']; //Get percentage of value 2
$value_2 = $Array_Generator['Values']['Value_2']['Value']; //Get actual value of value 2

$max = $Array_Generator['Max_Values'];  //Get max

$maxa = $val_1p/100 * $max;  //Get total number of value 1s to generate based on the percentage of they existence within the 200 =40
$maxb = $val_2p/100 * $max;  //Get total number of value 1s to generate based on the percentage of they existence within the 200 =40

$ff_1 = array_fill(0,$maxa,$value_1); //Make array with 20% of value 1
$ff_2 = array_fill(0,$maxb,$value_2); //Make array with 80% of value 2

$ff = array_merge($ff_1,$ff_2); //Combine the seperate arrays

shuffle($ff); //Shuffle them
print_r($ff);
```

Comment: I would suggest you revise your solution a bit. For one, you don't handle the calculation of the number of elements correctly. It works fine for a nicely divisible number like 200, but try it with, for example, 3. Other than that, it is unnecessarily complicated - there is no need to create a string to be exploded into an array - you can create an array directly (see [`array_fill`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)). And even with this method of creating a string first, I don't understand why you created a template first and then replaced it for actual values.

Comment: Another thing to consider: the structure of `$Array_Generator` can be assumed static - otherwise the whole question wouldn't make any sense. That makes your two loops just to get the values and percentages a complete overkill. Use direct array access like you do with max value (and I can't even begin to understand what that first empty loop was meant to do - perhaps you misplaced a closing bracket).

Comment: Matei Zoc I have updated the answer in attempts to deal with some of @El_Vanja 's concerns...It still produces the same results